# C++ openGL GLFW xcode parse expecting bracket that is already there

Tags: c++

Below is my code. The error only occurs after I try to run the code, when I click the info button it says it's to match the bracket connected to my float function even though I already have a closing bracket.  I am new to OpenGL/GLFW and am new to Xcode any help is greatly appreciated.
[Photo of code in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfXHu.png)

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 640
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 480
int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;
    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_WIDTH, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    };
    glViewport(0.0f, 0.0f, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity(  );
    glOrtho(0, SCREEN_WIDTH, 0, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0, 1);
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        
    float vertices[]{
    0,300, 0.0
    300,300.0.0                  **Error located here "Expected '}'"**              
    300,0,0.0
    0,0,0.0
        
    };
    
    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        /* Render here */
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
        glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        
        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are some missing `,` at the end of the lines.

Comment: @Rabbid76 thank you so much man, I'm blind as a bat. :)